# Guidelines on assessing how data is gathered

Tags: sampling, dataset

I will be working with a dataset sample which I will use for optimization purposes. However, before I start, I want to briefly analyze data in order to get a better sense and identify possible directions to explore.

My problem is I don't know how the data was sampled, which sampling method was used or whether the same method was used for all parts of the data, and I'd like to get a sense about those. One of my ideas was to form subsamples from the sample and perform hypothesis tests but I don't know if this should be the way to go.

I am aware that this is a vague question, but I was wondering if you could point out references/lectures/papers or comments in order to help me have a good start.

Comment: Something unclear to me: Your first sentence is suggestive of data *exploration*, while you later report you want to perform statistical tests (which depends on sampling scheme, of course). Can you clarify?

Comment: I see no way to test how a sample is drawn from a population when all you have is the sample.

Comment: There are some very limited things you could do in very specific circumstances... forming an expectation of what a value "should" be and comparing to the data. If you wanted to see if a survey was conducted online or not, and have a question about computer ownership, and online survey would yield ~100%... but it would be limited to very general questions.